# Rollup and de-normalize data using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have below scenario where we have 4 record and using `awk` I am getting proper data as expected but I am not able to understand how `awk` is working here, what is the meaning of each a[] here. can someone explain below `awk` command in brief? Specifically "If" part.

```
$ cat temp.dat
abc|v1
abc|v2
def|v1
def|v3

$ awk -F"|" '{if(a[$1]){a[$1]=a[$1]","$2} else { a[$1]=$2}} END {for (i in a) {print i"|"a[i]}}' temp.dat
def|v1,v3
abc|v1,v2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type of questions tend to go down as off-topic since not belonging to scope of this site, but let me help you understand it, as you are relatively new to the site.

The breakdown of the command (literally):-

- `-F"|"` is to setting the input-field-separator, i.e. to let `awk` know on the de-limiter to parse words from, in this case being `|`. `awk` runs the command(s) on each line of the input-file.
- In an `awk` array (`a[]`), the if-condition checks if there is a value in the array for subscript `$1`, i.e. when parsing first line it checks if value `a[abc]` exists. Since it is not likely to exist, the else-clause stores the value of `$2` in the array variable (`v1`) i.e. `a[abc]=v1`
- On parsing the next line (`abc|v2`), since now the value in `a[abc]` exists the if-clause is executed. `a[$1]=a[$1]","$2` literally means, overwrite the value in `a[abc]` with already existing value(`v1`), comma (`,`) and the current value of `$2` i.e. `a[abc]` now has `v1,v2`
- The same above two steps happen for the next set of lines which stores `a[def]=v1,v3`

Now that the array is filled, the `END` clause of `awk` is met. By general logic, the statements within this clause is executed once `awk` has parsed the file in-line and did some modifications with it.

In your case though, `END{}` statements just the contents of the array are printed.

- `for (i in a)` means for each of subscripts in the array i.e. `i in (abc,def)`
- `print i"|"a[i]}` prints the value of `i` being `(abc,def)` and the value of the index from the array i.e. `a[abc] and a[def]` with `|` in middle.

Read more about `awk` [in-this-tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: wrt `it checks if value a[abc] exists` - no, it doesn't. `if(a[abc])` checks if the value of array element `a[abc]` is neither null nor zero. If you wanted to check for a value `a[abc]` existing then the test would be `if(abc in a)` which is a very different test and is, I suspect, what whoever wrote the code really intended to write.